# OpenGL 3.0 GLSL 130 fragment shader compile error

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to compile a simple colored triangle example with OpenGL 3 (GLSL 130) but my fragment shader never compiles. The error reported is always

```
syntax error unexpected $end
```

My vertex shader compiles and shows the geometry but the fragment shader fails.

Here are the sources (very simple one):
Vertex.vs:

```
attribute vec3 vertex_position;
attribute vec3 vertex_color;

varying vec4 out_color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
    out_color = vec4(vertex_color, 1.0);
}
```

And fragment.fs:

```
varying vec4 out_color;

void main(void)    
{    
    gl_FragColor = out_color;            
}
```

[EDIT] Here is my shader compile code:

```
char *loadShader(const char *fname)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    long size = 0;
    if (!fp)
        return NULL;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp) + 1;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* data = (char*) malloc((sizeof(char) * size));
    ::fread(data, 1, size, fp);
    data[size-1] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    return data;
}

Shader::Shader(const char *fname)
    : m_data(NULL),
      ID(0)
{
    if (fname)
        m_data = ilian::loadShader(fname);
}

Shader::Shader(const char *data, size_t size)
{
    if (data && size >0)
    {
        m_data = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
        ::memmove(m_data, data, size);
    }
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    if (m_data)
    {
        free(m_data);
        m_data = NULL;
    }
    glDeleteShader(ID);
    std::cout << "~Shader()\n";
}

std::string Shader::data()
{
    std::string s((char*)m_data);
    return s;
}

GLuint &Shader::getID()
{
    return ID;
}

void Shader::createShader(ShaderType type)
{
    GLint res = -1;
    switch (type)
    {
    case VERTEX:
        ID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        break;
    case FRAGMENT:
        ID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    const GLchar* source = (const GLchar*) data().c_str();
    int shader_len = data().length();

    glShaderSource(ID, 1, &source, &shader_len);
    glCompileShader(ID);
    glGetShaderiv(ID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &res);

    if (res == GL_TRUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Shader Compile OK!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Shader Compile FAIL!\n";
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        //The maxLength includes the NULL character
        std::vector<GLchar> infoLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(ID, maxLength, &maxLength, &infoLog[0]);
        std::cout << (char*)infoLog.data() << "\n";
        //We don't need the shader anymore.
        glDeleteShader(ID);
    }
}

GLProgram::GLProgram(const char *vs_source, const char *fs_source)
    : ID(0), vs(nullptr), fs(nullptr)
{
    vs = new Shader(vs_source);
    fs = new Shader(fs_source);
    vs->createShader(VERTEX);
    fs->createShader(FRAGMENT);
}

GLProgram::~GLProgram()
{
    if (vs)
        delete vs;
    if (fs)
        delete fs;
}

VAO &GLProgram::getVertexArrayObject()
{
    return vao;
}

bool GLProgram::createProgram()
{
    static GLint msg;

    ID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ID, vs->getID());
    glAttachShader(ID, fs->getID());
    glLinkProgram(ID);

    glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &msg);

    std::cout << "Link status: (" <<msg
              << ")"<< std::endl;
    if (!msg)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
        if(infoLen > 1)
        {
           char* infoLog = new char[infoLen];
           glGetProgramInfoLog(ID, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);
           printf("Error linking program:\n%s\n", infoLog);
           delete [] infoLog;
        }
    }
}

void GLProgram::bind(int location, const char *attribyte)
{
    glBindAttribLocation(ID, location, attribyte);
}

void GLProgram::useProgram()
{
    glUseProgram(ID);
    glBindVertexArray(vao.ID());
}
```

Comment: How do you compile the shader? We need a [mcve].

Comment: Done. Hope that helps.

Comment: Why are you constructing a std::string from the char* just to convert it then back to a char*?

Comment: I was just printing to see if I was getting the correct text.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I did that. Actually the length fix was something I stumbled upon when I was browsing how to fix it. Originally it was NULL. Either ways it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to an invalid memory address to `glShaderSource`. This happens because you try to get the `c_str()` pointer from a temporary string object in this line:

```
const GLchar* source = (const GLchar*) data().c_str();
```

Right after this line, the temporary string returned by data() gets deleted and the source pointer points to an invalid memory address.

The shortest (but ugly) fix to your code is to make sure that the string object still lives when you use the pointer by storing it:

```
auto data_str = data();
const GLchar* source = (const GLchar*)data_str.c_str();
```

But since the construction of the whole string object is completely useless in your code (and actually hurts performance because the string object creates a copy of the underlying char array), the better way is to return the char* instead of a new std::string in the data() function:

```
const char* Shader::data()
{
    return m_data;
}
```

and use it with:

```
 const GLchar* source = data();
```

Or even better: Do not use a char* with malloc in the first place and use the proper C++ methods to directly load a std::string from the file.

Comment: My bad! I saw it. Really a silly mistake. Thanks for the answer. I was trying to use the same method to print it as a string and to load the data unaware of the c_str() and the std ctor. Kind regards.